# How to remove single or double quotes from a string?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodejs. I now have a code like this.

```js
var array1 = ["a","b"];

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

which answers the bellow response :

```
"a"
"b"
```

But I need remove double quotes just like this:

```
a
b
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: An interesting question is why do you want to remove the double quotes? If you are going to output these to a file/page then depending on how you output them, they wouldn't have quotes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not occur in the Node shell and a Firefox window, both output the following:

```
a
b
```

But if it is still happening to you, you could do something like:

```
var array1 = ["a","b"];

array1.forEach(function(element) {
   console.log(element.replace(/"/g, ''));
});
```

This will replace all instances of " with nothingness.